# problema com a data

Tags: java, android

no meu aplicativo quando faço um pedido de venda, devesse informar a data do pedido e a data de emissão, a data do pedido eu pego automaticamente, já a data de emissão deve ser preenchida manualmente.

Depois dos inserts, eu exporto o banco do AVD e abro no SQLite experts e nenhuma data aprece, todas aparecem como "1899-12-30"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigos:

botao Insert do pedido:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());

            EditText data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtData);
            EditText emissao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmissao);
            EditText obs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtObs);

            String dataString = data.getText().toString();
            String emissaoString = emissao.getText().toString();
            String obsString = obs.getText().toString();
            String resultadoPe;
            String resultadoPp = null;

            Spinner spClientes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCliente);
            Spinner spCarteira = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCarteira);
            Spinner spPagamentos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPagamento);

            SQLiteCursor dadosClientes = (SQLiteCursor) spClientes.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spClientes.getSelectedItemPosition());

            SQLiteCursor dadosCarteira = (SQLiteCursor) spCarteira.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spCarteira.getSelectedItemPosition());

            SQLiteCursor dadosPagamentos = (SQLiteCursor) spPagamentos.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spPagamentos.getSelectedItemPosition());

            String idCliente = String.valueOf(dadosClientes.getInt(0));
            String idCarteira = String.valueOf(dadosCarteira.getInt(0));
            String idPagamento = String.valueOf(dadosPagamentos.getInt(0));

            crud.op = 2;

            resultadoPe = crud.insereDados(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null, null, null, idCliente, idPagamento, idCarteira, dataString,
                    emissaoString, obsString, null, null, null, null, null);

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), resultadoPe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Inseredados do pedido:

```
public String insereDados
        (String nome, String apelido, String cpf, String rg, String endereco, String bairro,
         String municipio, String uf, String cep, String email, String fone, String cla,
         String par, String car, String cpag, String data, String emissao, String obs, String ped,
         String pro, String quantidade, String unitario, String item /**String lpPcodigo,
         String lpDescri, String lpQtd, String lpPreco*/){

    long resultadoC = -1;
    long resultadoPe = -1;
    long resultadoPr = -1;
    //long resultadoLp = -1;
    db = banco.getWritableDatabase();


    switch (op){
        case 1://Insere cliente:
            ContentValues cvc;
            cvc = new ContentValues();

            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParNome(), nome);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParApelido(), apelido);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParCpf(), cpf);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParRg(), rg);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParEndereco(), endereco);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParBairro(), bairro);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParMunicipio(), municipio);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParUf(), uf);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParCep(), cep);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParEmail(), email);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParFone(), fone);

            resultadoC = db.insert(CriaBanco.getParTabela(), null, cvc);
            break;

        case 2://Insere Pedido
            ContentValues cvpe;
            cvpe = new ContentValues();

            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getClaId(), cla);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPparId(), par);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getCarId(), car);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getCpagId(), cpag);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedData(), data);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedEmissao(), emissao);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedObs(), obs);

            resultadoPe = db.insert(CriaBanco.getPedTabela(), null, cvpe);
            break;

        case 3: // Insere Pedido Produto

            ContentValues cvpr;
            cvpr = new ContentValues();

            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPppedId(), ped);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPpproId(), pro);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproQnt(), quantidade);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproUnit(), unitario);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproItem(), item);

            resultadoPr = db.insert(CriaBanco.getPprodTabela(), null, cvpr);
            break;

    }
    db.close();

    if (resultadoC != -1){
        return "Cliente inserido com sucesso!";
    }else if(resultadoPe != -1 || resultadoPr != -1){
        return "Pedido realizado com sucesso!";
    }/**else if(resultadoLp != -1) {
        return "Produto adicionado a lista com sucesso!";
    }*/else{
        return "Erro ao inserir registro (cliente/pedido)!";
    }
}
```

uso Date edittext tanto na data do pedido quanto na data de emissão.

outra pergunta, tem como modificar formatação da data?

por exemplo, aparece assim automaticamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aparece 13 de maio de 2016, não tem como modificar e aparecer como 13/05/2016?

e tem como modificar com o codigo para na hora de inserir a data modifique as "/" por "-"?

obrigado desde ja

---EDIT---

como eu pego a data automaticamente:

```
final String currentDataTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente da seguinte maneira:

```
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/"+"MM"+"/yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: deu certo, mas ainda continua salvando errado a data no banco, eu acho que é por causa das barras...